# Problem with ExpoMediaLibrary when importing module

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to use `expo-media-library` to allow my user to download image.

I have some problem when importing the module: `import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';`

I get this error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ExponentMediaLibrary.default.MediaType')` triggered in the file `node_modules/tinycolor2/tinycolor.js`

I don't know how to solve this, any clue would be appreciated !